# How to stop unsubscribing the observable when error

Tags: angular, events, rxjs, observable, server-sent-events

I am using server send events(SSE) in the Angular application. Find the below code of service

```js
listenNotifications(){
  const apiUrl='https://example.com/v1/notification/sse';
  const eventSource=new EventSource(apiUrl);
  return new Observable<NotificationSseResponse>(
      (subscriber: Subscriber<NotificationSseResponse>) => {
        eventSource.onmessage = (event: MessageEvent) => {
          const notificationData: NotificationSseResponse = JSON.parse(event.data);
          subscriber.next(notificationData);
        };
        eventSource.onerror = (event: ErrorEvent) => {
          subscriber.error(event);
        };
        return function unsubscribe() {
          eventSource.close();
        };
      }
    );
}
```

If there is an error, the error block `subscriber.error(event)` is executing. So the observable is triggering the `unsubscribe` function and then the SSE is closing the connection. I am unable to receive the notification event from the event source continuously when there is an error

**Need**

- I have to reconnect with SSE even there is an error
- I have to pass the error from the service when there is an error(like I have done)

**Question**

- Is RxJx observable having the option to stop triggering unsubscribe when calling `subscribe.error()`?
- Is there any better way to achieve the SSE(server send events) with unsubscribe?

Comment: I *think* that if you pipe to [retry()](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/retry) it will unsubscribe first and then re-subscribe, which is probably appropriate for your case. You can also pipe to [catchError()](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/catchError) to do some custom handling.

Answer (score 1):

You can emit the error object as normal emission and handle error object manually, without triggering `unsubscribe()`

```
eventSource.onerror = (event: ErrorEvent) => {
  subscriber.next({error:event});
};

// usage 
listenNotifications().pipe(
   mergeMap(obj=>{
     // pass to downstream when no error 
     if(!obj.error) return of(obj);
     // ...handle your error
     // then return empty
    return empty();
  }),
  map(..... downstream data processing ) 
)
```

Comment: This is fine. But I am expecting that, it should receive the error in error method of the observer

Comment: correct me if i am wrong, but i think even with `retry` you won't be able to reach the error observer.

Comment: Yes. Your are right

Comment: Once observable throw error you will have to handle it and will need resubscribe, so the above solution will let you bypass that